# How do I make my app scroll the entire page?

Tags: android, performance, scroll

I don't have any pictures so this might be hard to explain. I am building an app for someone and when you load a page on the app and try to scroll to the bottom of said page, it only scrolls until the visible part is out of view. Then it acts like it is at the bottom of the page without really being at the bottom. For instance, you open Twitter, look at the bottom of your screen, then scroll down, and the app only scrolls until what was at the bottom of your screen is just off screen at the top.

I saw somewhere that the "layout_height" needed to equal "0dp" under your fragment section. However, mine was already set to that. My company has a few apps and I don't see a difference in the code between this one and one that doesn't have this issue. Any advice?

Edit:
I am using Cordova and this is my content_main.xml folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_content_main"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: show me your xml code

Comment: I have quite a bit of xml code. Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: if I see the code after I will explain

Comment: I made and edit with the code.

Comment: u can use RelativeLayout

Comment: androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout this u can u Relativelayout

Comment: I posted code check my answer just suggestion

Answer (score -1):

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_content_main"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>
   </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Sorry but this did not fix my current issue.